# Texture Baking (Diffuse) color seems off

Tags: uv, texture-baking, baking

I encountered a problem while baking my textures. I got a white color texture for my model but when I baked it the results became blueish.

Below is the before and after of baking.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What bake settings did you use?

Comment: diffuse, color, indirect and direct are all checked. however when I only bake the color there's no problem, in other color too there's no problem even direct and indirect are turned on